# How to refresh explorer after a registry change

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-8, pinvoke, explorer

I'm trying to refresh the system (Windows 8) after changing a value in the registry, this value affects the explorer settings, Is the value to show/hide the checkboxes:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    RegEdit.Set_Value("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced", _
                      "AutoCheckSelect", "1", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
End Sub
```

And to refresh the system I use this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub
```

I've tried a lot of flag combinations.

The problem is the explorer windows refreshes but the checkboxes does not appear (or does not been removed), I still need to press F5 inside each explorer window for a full change-refresh.

This is the full code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("shell32.dll")> _
Shared Sub SHChangeNotify( _
ByVal wEventID As HChangeNotifyEventID, _
ByVal uFlags As HChangeNotifyFlags, _
ByVal dwItem1 As IntPtr, _
ByVal dwItem2 As IntPtr)
End Sub

<Flags()> _
Public Enum HChangeNotifyFlags
    ' <summary>
    ' The <i>dwItem1</i> and <i>dwItem2</i> parameters are DWORD values.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_DWORD = &H3
    ' <summary>
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> and <i>dwItem2</i> are the addresses of ITEMIDLIST structures that
    ' represent the item(s) affected by the change.
    ' Each ITEMIDLIST must be relative to the desktop folder.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_IDLIST = &H0
    ' <summary>
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> and <i>dwItem2</i> are the addresses of null-terminated strings of
    ' maximum length MAX_PATH that contain the full path names
    ' of the items affected by the change.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_PATHA = &H1
    ' <summary>
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> and <i>dwItem2</i> are the addresses of null-terminated strings of
    ' maximum length MAX_PATH that contain the full path names
    ' of the items affected by the change.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_PATHW = &H5
    ' <summary>
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> and <i>dwItem2</i> are the addresses of null-terminated strings that
    ' represent the friendly names of the printer(s) affected by the change.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_PRINTERA = &H2
    ' <summary>
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> and <i>dwItem2</i> are the addresses of null-terminated strings that
    ' represent the friendly names of the printer(s) affected by the change.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_PRINTERW = &H6
    ' <summary>
    ' The function should not return until the notification
    ' has been delivered to all affected components.
    ' As this flag modifies other data-type flags it cannot by used by itself.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_FLUSH = &H1000
    ' <summary>
    ' The function should begin delivering notifications to all affected components
    ' but should return as soon as the notification process has begun.
    ' As this flag modifies other data-type flags it cannot by used by itself.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT = &H2000
End Enum


<Flags()> _
Public Enum HChangeNotifyEventID
    ' <summary>
    ' All events have occurred.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_ALLEVENTS = &H7FFFFFFF

    ' <summary>
    ' A file type association has changed. <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/>
    ' must be specified in the <i>uFlags</i> parameter.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> and <i>dwItem2</i> are not used and must be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = &H8000000

    ' <summary>
    ' The attributes of an item or folder have changed.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the item or folder that has changed.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_ATTRIBUTES = &H800

    ' <summary>
    ' A nonfolder item has been created.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the item that was created.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_CREATE = &H2

    ' <summary>
    ' A nonfolder item has been deleted.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the item that was deleted.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_DELETE = &H4

    ' <summary>
    ' A drive has been added.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the root of the drive that was added.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_DRIVEADD = &H100

    ' <summary>
    ' A drive has been added and the Shell should create a new window for the drive.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the root of the drive that was added.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_DRIVEADDGUI = &H10000

    ' <summary>
    ' A drive has been removed. <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the root of the drive that was removed.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_DRIVEREMOVED = &H80

    ' <summary>
    ' Not currently used.
    ' </summary>
    ' SHCNE_EXTENDED_EVENT = &H4000000

    ' <summary>
    ' The amount of free space on a drive has changed.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the root of the drive on which the free space changed.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_FREESPACE = &H40000

    ' <summary>
    ' Storage media has been inserted into a drive.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the root of the drive that contains the new media.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_MEDIAINSERTED = &H20

    ' <summary>
    ' Storage media has been removed from a drive.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the root of the drive from which the media was removed.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_MEDIAREMOVED = &H40

    ' <summary>
    ' A folder has been created. <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/>
    ' or <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the folder that was created.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_MKDIR = &H8

    ' <summary>
    ' A folder on the local computer is being shared via the network.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the folder that is being shared.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_NETSHARE = &H200

    ' <summary>
    ' A folder on the local computer is no longer being shared via the network.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the folder that is no longer being shared.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_NETUNSHARE = &H400

    ' <summary>
    ' The name of a folder has changed.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the previous pointer to an item identifier list (PIDL) or name of the folder.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> contains the new PIDL or name of the folder.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_RENAMEFOLDER = &H20000

    ' <summary>
    ' The name of a nonfolder item has changed.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the previous PIDL or name of the item.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> contains the new PIDL or name of the item.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_RENAMEITEM = &H1

    ' <summary>
    ' A folder has been removed.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the folder that was removed.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_RMDIR = &H10

    ' <summary>
    ' The computer has disconnected from a server.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the server from which the computer was disconnected.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_SERVERDISCONNECT = &H4000

    ' <summary>
    ' The contents of an existing folder have changed
    ' but the folder still exists and has not been renamed.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST"/> or
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATH"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' <i>dwItem1</i> contains the folder that has changed.
    ' <i>dwItem2</i> is not used and should be <see langword="null"/>.
    ' If a folder has been created deleted or renamed use SHCNE_MKDIR SHCNE_RMDIR or
    ' SHCNE_RENAMEFOLDER respectively instead.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_UPDATEDIR = &H1000

    ' <summary>
    ' An image in the system image list has changed.
    ' <see cref="HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_DWORD"/> must be specified in <i>uFlags</i>.
    ' </summary>
    SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE = &H8000
End Enum


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    RegEdit.Set_Value("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced", _
                      "AutoCheckSelect", "0", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Its just my suggestion.why don't you use timer?

Comment: @sentil kumar Thanks but can you be more specific please, A timer for which intention? the key is modified and after that I try to refresh the system, then why do you think I need a timer and what you think the timer tick would do?.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using SHChangeNotify() with SHCNE_ALLEVENTS events, it may work. It may refresh the explorer after that. Otherwise you have to think some other tricks

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do something similar - update a registry setting for the start menu and then immediately have the start menu reflect the changes.

[The solution from this MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/ce540c7d-a113-4f39-956e-0af6bc91abd3/force-updaterefresh-of-windows-start-menu) worked for me perfectly.

> You could try broadcasting a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.  For example:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, IntPtr lpdwResult);

    private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
    private const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
    private const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, null, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, it does not worked for me, I still need to press "F5" to see the changes on the open explorer.

Comment: Anyways this is very interesting, maybe it works with other specific changes, please could you specify with what kind of system changes have you tried?

Comment: This was specifically to update the Use Large Icons setting of the start menu.  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]` `"Start_LargeMFUIcons"=dword:00000000`

Answer (score 1):

you could try some cheap tricks.

```
- Send a "F5" keystroke to the explorer window so you don't have to do it manually.
- kill explorer.exe, and relaunch it.
```

Take a look at this.
[How to refresh Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940603/how-to-refresh-windows-explorer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your second suggestion will be effective but my purpose is to refresh the explorer windows for that atribute change, not to kill all opened windows by restarting the explorer process.The suggestion of sending F5 In that case I will need to list all opened explorer windows,activate-focus each window one by one and then send the F5 key... I think tat is not much efficient if the user hace 50 open windows. My intention is to not user-interact with the windows,thats why Im trying to use API to do it in a silent and improved way or looking for a similar way to do it.