# Is there any taskbar API to apply registry changes immediately?

Tags: c++, c, windows-10, registry, explorer

When I/We change the taskbar settings with right click on taskbar > taskbar settings the changes apply immediately but when I make changes in registry settings I have to reset explorer.exe to apply the changes.

Is there any API to apply registry changes immediately? or another idea?

Comment: Does the user want you to change the taskbar settings?

Comment: @user253751 yes, the user himself make the changes from the program, it's a program to simulate the taskbar settings

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no easy way in general, since each application has to implement some way to notice registry changes. So if the application only reads the registry key at startup you are out of luck, but there is an event system in Windows to notify (willing) applications about registry changes. Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendnotifymessagea)

```
SendNotifyMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0 );
```

Other maybe helpful links:

- [Force update start menu after registry change](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/ce540c7d-a113-4f39-956e-0af6bc91abd3/force-updaterefresh-of-windows-start-menu)
- [How to refresh explorer after a registry change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732200/how-to-refresh-explorer-after-a-registry-change)
- Documentation of the [WMI System Registry Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/regprov/system-registry-provider)

Comment: thanks for answer, I called these functions immediately after changing the registry but the changes didn't apply...